# Recorrer un json en Javascript con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo un json de la siguiente manera

```
result= {"cambios":[{"idCard":"5ac8798039a4cff62f780f8e","idList":"5ab7c3aec0fa3a36a67b1c87"},{"idCard":"5ab7c3cc83270bcf19c2774f","idList":"5ab7c3aec0fa3a36a67b1c87"}]}
```

Quiero acceder a idCard e idList, estoy probando de la siguiente manera:

```
function modificarLista(result){
     alert("Estoy en cambiar de lista" + result.cambios);
     alert("Estoy en cambiar de lista" + result);

     $("#res2").text(result.cambios);
     $("#res3").text(result);

       $.each(result.cambios, function(i, item) {
            $("#res2").text("en el each"+ item.idCard);
            alert(item.idCard);
            alert(item.idList);
        });
};
```

Creo que mi error está en que directamente recorro el array, y me falta recorrer 
"cambios" pero no se muy bien que me falta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al principio puede ser un poco lío, pero fíjate en el ejemplo:

```js
result= {"cambios":[{"idCard":"5ac8798039a4cff62f780f8e","idList":"5ab7c3aec0fa3a36a67b1c87"},{"idCard":"5ab7c3cc83270bcf19c2774f","idList":"5ab7c3aec0fa3a36a67b1c87"}]};

$.each(result.cambios, function(i, item) {
    $("#res2").text("en el each");
    alert(item.idCard);
    alert(item.idList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res2"></div>
```

Como ves, la primera modificación que he hecho es cambiar el elemento que vas a recorrer. No recorrerás 'result' sino 'result.cambios'. Al hacer esto, la variable item toma dicho valor y sólo tienes que hacer referencia a idCard o idList.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero resutl.cambios me devuelve null, si muestro antes del each result me muestra el string  que indiqué en la pregunta, pero result.cambios es null porque puede ser?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo estas mostrando? Y, ¿de qué manera estas asignando el valor a 'result'?

Comment: He modificado la pregunta, el result lo recibo del server,

Comment: Hola @zeross, creo que tu solución debería funcionar sin problemas (aunque no puedo comprobarlo porque estoy en un móvil). Prueba a editar tu respuesta para crear un snippet ejecutable y que se pueda ver funcionando. Para ello pulsa en el icono que parece esto `<>` en el editor de texto. Un saludo.

Comment: solucionado me pasaba parsear result, gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

en la documentacion de jquery hay ejmplos, este es uno de los ejemplos.

```
<script>
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };

jQuery.each( obj, function( i, val ) {
  $( "#" + i ).append( document.createTextNode( " - " + val ) );
  console.log(i + " val: " + val)
});

var ejemplo = {
                "cambios":[
                            {
                                "idCard":"5ac8798039a4cff62f780f8e",
                                "idList":"5ab7c3aec0fa3a36a67b1c87"
                            },
                            {   
                                "idCard":"5ab7c3cc83270bcf19c2774f",
                                "idList":"5ab7c3aec0fa3a36a67b1c87"
                            }
                          ]
              }


jQuery.each( ejemplo, function( i, val ) {

    jQuery.each( val, function( x, valor ) {

      console.log( valor.idCard)
    });
});
</script>
```

segun veo tienes un objeto, que contiene un propiedad de tipo array y dentro de esa tienes objetos, seria question que interadas el primer array para poder acceder a la propiedad que contiene los objetos.
este una improbisacion, seria cuestion que lo analizaras y vieras una forma mas de solucionar.
espero te ayude

Comment: He probado tu ejemplo y me funciona correctamente, mi problema es que mi var ejemplo, lo recibo en desde un ajax y he comprobado que no devuelve vacio, pero no lo recorre, también he probado a declarar: var ejemplo=result pero no consigo que se recorra, sabes porqué puede ser

Comment: @Silvia tal cez deberias poner mas de talles, si realmente esta recibiendo un objeto o un array.